# How can I dynamically set SEO titles and descriptions for my Shopify products

Tags: shopify

I want to set all my products titles to be like {Product_titles |  Store Name}. How can I set that?
The issue I'm seeing is that the products already have some manually put SEO titles, as we have added lots of products recently we want a single formula for all products SEO titles and meta descriptions.
The template already has this dynamic code for titles

```
<title>
      {{ page_title }}{% if current_tags %}{% assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags }}{% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}{% endif %}{% unless page_title contains shop.name %} &ndash; {{ shop.name }}{% endunless %}
    </title>
```

and for meta description

```
{%- if page_description -%}
      <meta name="description" content="{{ page_description | escape }}">
```

I want to keep different types of titles and meta descriptions for products, collections, pages and blog posts.

Can I edit them in shopify theme.liquid or is there any app that can help us in this?

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically change title's on the Product page only.

Find your `<title></title>` tags in your theme.

Add an `{% if %}` statement in there. Like so:

`<title>{% if template == "product" %}Hey I'm a product page{% endif %}</title>`

You can have quite a few if statements within the title tag.

In your case:
`<title>{% if template == "product" %}{{ product.title }} | {{ shop.name }}{% endif %}</title>`